# Extracting list of counties that are nested within larger geographic units in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, spatial-join, county

I have one layer/shapefile that consists of county boundaries and another layer of larger geographic divisions that each contain about 15 counties. I basically want a list of all the counties that are in each of these larger geographic divisions. The larger super-county divisions generally follow county boundaries but there are some that don't follow county lines.  I was told earlier that a spatial join is the way to go, but after having exhausted (I think) all the options in both QGIS and Python's Geopandas it looks like a spatial join doesn't quite do what I want: create a table of counties with an simple indicator of which area(s) they are in (so if the county is in two areas there are two records, etc.). The spatial joins so far have also been including divisions that touch the county, whereas I just want the counties that are spatially in the larger division. Also, the "contains" and "within" commands don't seem to be successfully creating any inner matches. I'm using QGIS 3.4 for Mac.

Comment: Possible solution, though I don't think it will produce what you want: Create `centroids` for the counties, the `join attributes by location` for the larger units to the counties, then the counties' centroids will have the name of the larger units added to them. This gives you a table with the counties and the larger unit they belong to - this does not give you a table with which counties are contained within a larger unit. Also, it doesn't cover misaligned borders.

Comment: That actually worked really well, thanks! Of course, as you indicated, it doesn't solve the misaligned borders part, but but now I'm wondering if the shapefile I have is slightly off, which would explain why the "intersection" predicate is flagging not only the counties that intersect, but also those that touch but don't intersect.